# Converting Multipart annotation to Singlepart causes stale record

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, annotation

When converting a feature-linked multipart annotation to a singlepart in either the context menu within ArcMap, or with the ArcObjects  interface I am left with an annotation that becomes stale.

The only way I can fix this is by moving the annotation a little bit, in this case its in follow feature mode.  This also generally makes the rotation handles in the corners appear.  It also populates the angle field in the annotation featureclass.

Converting to a singlepart annotation does work without error.  The problem manifests when you try to edit a field such as "Angle" in the annotation featureclass.  It always gives me the error "Invalid Angle".  By default, upon conversion, the angle field will still say 0.

Is there some method within ArcObjects that will perform the same sort of action that moving an annotation does to "refresh" itself when converted to a singlepart?

Relevant Code snippet:

```
var annoFeature = feature as IAnnotationFeature2;
var element = annoFeature.Annotation;
((IMultiPartTextElement)element).ConvertToSinglePart();
feature.Store()
```

Comment: Did you try setting [IAnnoClassAdmin3.UpdateOnShapeChange](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IAnnoClassAdmin3_UpdateOnShapeChange.htm) to true?

Comment: Or perhaps just setting `IFeature.Shape = IFeature.ShapeCopy` then calling `IFeature.Store()` ... this might trigger the same thing that moving the feature does.

Comment: I believe that applies to something else - to the "annotation class" itself.  When that is set true (which it is in this case) it will adjust (usually move) the annotation with its feature-linked feature is modified.  Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Setting it to ShapeCopy does not work either.

Comment: Hmm, after you ConvertTooSingle part, if you cast feature to `IFeatureChanges`,  is `ShapeChanged` true?

Comment: Also, did you try `IMultiPartTextElement.SynchronizeParts` after converting to single part?

Comment: FeatureChanges is still false after performing that operation.  I did try SynchronizeParts before writing the question but I couldn't see where it was doing anything at all.  I did just test something else, it looks like converting the curvature to "straight" or "horizontal" also triggers the refresh.  I don't see a way to do this in ArcObjects though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem revolved around the fact that despite after converting to a single part, the annotation still had a curved baseline.  When converting to "straight", either through the context menu in ArcMap or in ArcObjects, it automatically corrects the issue.

For posterity, here is the snippet I created to mimic the convert to straight context menu functionality.

```
var pointCollection = (IPointCollection)element.Geometry;
IPolyline polyline = new PolylineClass();
polyline.FromPoint = pointCollection.Point[0];
polyline.ToPoint = pointCollection.Point[pointCollection.PointCount - 1];
```

Just set the symbol element geometry to the newly created polyline.